# Python - Datetime not accounting for leap second properly?

Tags: python, datetime, leap-second

I am parsing some data that has the leapsecond timestampe datetime `2012-06-30T23:59:60.209215`. I used following code to parse that string and convert to a datetime object:

```
    nofrag, frag = t.split('.')
    nofrag_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(nofrag, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    dt = nofrag_dt.replace(microsecond=int(frag))
```

Python documentation claims that this shouldn't be an issue as `%S` accepts `[0, 61]`. But, I get this error with the above timestamp

```
nofrag_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(nofrag, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ValueError: second must be in 0..59
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does the documentation claim that? http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html says "Unlike the time module, the datetime module does not support leap seconds."

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime points to http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime, where http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime claims to support leap second

Comment: Ah. The problem isn't the parsing; that is done by `time.strptime` and works fine; the problem is that if the seconds are > 59, it can't be converted back to a `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: unlrelated: `int(frag)` may return a wrong number of microseconds e.g., `.123` should correspond to `123000` microseconds, not `123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
import time
import datetime 
t = '2012-06-30T23:59:60.209215'
nofrag, frag = t.split('.')
nofrag_dt = time.strptime(nofrag, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(nofrag_dt))
dt = ts.replace(microsecond=int(frag))
print(dt)
```

Output is:

```
2012-07-01 00:00:00.209215
```

Comment: note: the round trip through the local time may fail (e.g., during DST transitions) and it is *unnecessary* as [my answer demonstrates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21029510/4279).

Answer (score 8):

[The documentation for `%S` says](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> Unlike the time module, the datetime module does not support leap seconds.

The time string `"2012-06-30T23:59:60.209215"` implies that the time is in UTC (it is the last leap second at the moment):

```
import time
from calendar import timegm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_string = '2012-06-30T23:59:60.209215'
time_string, dot, us = time_string.partition('.')
utc_time_tuple = time.strptime(time_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=timegm(utc_time_tuple))
if dot:
    dt = dt.replace(microsecond=datetime.strptime(us, '%f').microsecond)
print(dt)
# -> 2012-07-01 00:00:00.209215
```

Comment: How does it imply that the time is in UTC?  I see no trailing `Z` or `+00:00`.

Comment: @MattJohnson: look up the time of the last leap second (it is the same time moment around the world).

Comment: Ah! Very nice!  You got me there! :)

Comment: `time_string.rpartition('.')` should be `time_string.partition('.')`, since if there is no dot then the former makes `time_string` the empty string and `ms` gets the non-trivial value.

Comment: @unutbu: thank you. I don't know why I've used `.rpartition()` here.