# How to convert python timestamp string to epoch?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, epoch

I have the following string:

```
mytime = "2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z"
```

How do I convert it to epoch in python?

I tried:

```
import time
p = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
int(time.mktime(time.strptime(s, p)))
```

But it does not work with the `31.807Z`.

Comment: how did you use %S  get something like `.807Z` ?  %S shows as  a decimal number

Answer (score 40):

There are two parts:

1. Convert the time string into a broken-down time. See [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)
2. [Convert the UTC time to "seconds since the Epoch" (POSIX timestamp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

utc_time = datetime.strptime("2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
epoch_time = (utc_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
# -> 1236472051.807
```

If you are sure that you want to ignore fractions of a second and to get an integer result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from calendar import timegm

utc_time = time.strptime("2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
epoch_time = timegm(utc_time)
# -> 1236472051
```

To support timestamps that correspond to a leap second such as `Wed July 1 2:59:60 MSK 2015`, you could [use a combination of `time.strptime()` and `datetime` (if you care about leap seconds you should take into account the microseconds too)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029510/4279).

Comment: what if you get "2009-03-08T00:27:31.807A" or any offset from zulu time?  but +1 for locale aware time conversion :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley In practice, rfc 3339 works unless you have some special requirements. `Z` is the only allowed letter https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6

Answer (score 16):

You are missing `.%fZ` from your format string.

```
p = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

The correct way to convert to epoch is to use `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

p = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
mytime = "2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z"
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
print((datetime.strptime(mytime, p) - epoch).total_seconds())
```

Or call int if you want to ignore fractions.

Comment: @JoranBeasley.   In my infinite wisdom I predicted it would always end in `Z`, I suppose you could always ignore `Z` and rstrip("Z")

Comment: don't use `time.mktime()` on UTC time!

Comment: here are the possible terminal characters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones .... its usually Z for most things but that letter has meaning that this discards :/  still solid answer of coarse :)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, yes, I read the post when you commented on joran's answer.

Comment: note: `mktime()` will return a wrong result here for any local timezone with non-zero UTC offset (most of them).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, yes, I answered using mktime as that was what the OP was using and corrected the formatting mistake which was causing the OP's problem, I was going to add the datetime solution but there were already an answer using a datetime approach so I thought it was pointless repeating the same answer until some mysterious stranger downvoted so I said I better add the datetime approach.

Comment: I've downvoted and left the comment about `mktime()`. "OP uses broken code in the question" is not a valid excuse for putting it in your answer. Personally, I add something like  `#XXX WRONG, DON'T USE` at the top of a code fragment if I have to include the broken code. It is not enough to put a valid answer somewhere at the bottom.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman!  Thank you, this worked excellently for me, though I have the exact same time format as the OP.

Answer (score 16):

`dateutil` has recently been added back to python packages, it's an easy one liner that handles formatting on its own.

```
from dateutil import parser
strtime = '2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z'
epoch = parser.parse(strtime).timestamp()
```

Comment: Only answers with no context and extra text are not the best. You are basically asking the OP to copy and paste your answer without knowing what the code does. Please provide an explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

dateutil is the only library i have found that correctly deals with the timezone offset identitifier (`Z`)

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

then

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
print date_parse("2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z")
#get timestamp

import calendar
dt =  date_parse("2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z")
timestamp1 = calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple())
```

Comment: probably a more robust solution.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it is less robust if you want to reject timestamps that  use a wrong format. `dateutil` may accept too much.

Comment: it is an overkill to use `dateutil` for that. You can parse the time string using only stdlib in both Python 2 and 3. `timegm()` is ok if you don't care about fractions of a second.

Comment: not if you dont want to lose the information imparted by the terminal letter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The only allowed letter is Z. Read [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
import datetime
epoch = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)

mytime = "2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z"
myformat = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
mydt = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, myformat)
val = (mydt - epoch).total_seconds()

print(val)
> 1236472051.81
repr(val)
> '1236472051.807'
```

Notes:

- When using `time.strptime()`, the returned [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) does not support sub-second precision.
- The `%f` [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is for microseconds. When parsing it need not be the full 6 digits.

Answer (score 1):

This code works in Python 3.6 to convert a datetime string to epoch in UTC or local timezone.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import tzutc, tzlocal

mydate = '2020-09-25'
mytime = '06:00:00'

epoch1970 = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())

myepochutc = int((datetime.strptime(mydate + ' ' + mytime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=tzutc()) - epoch1970).total_seconds()*1000)

myepochlocal = int((datetime.strptime(mydate + ' ' + mytime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=tzlocal()) - epoch1970).total_seconds()*1000)

#epoch will be in milliseconds
print(myepochutc)   #if mydate/mytime was in utc
print(myepochlocal) #if mydate/mytime was in local timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3.7+** The string format in question can be parsed by `strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
>>> datetime.datetime(2009, 3, 8, 0, 27, 31, 807000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Another option using the built-in `datetime.fromisoformat()`: As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date) thread linked by @jfs, `fromisoformat()` doesn't parse the 'Z' character to UTC although this is part of the [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) definitions. A little work-around can make it work - some will consider this nasty but it's [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418) after all.

```
from datetime import datetime
mytime = "2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z"
datetime.fromisoformat(mytime.replace("Z", "+00:00")).timestamp()
>>> 1236472051.807
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418