# Python: convert date from string to number

Tags: python, string, time, char

how I have a simple question. I need to convert a date in string format to a number:

```
time = '2014-03-05 07:22:26.976637+00:00'
type(time)
      str
```

I would like to convert this date to a unique number

Thank you.

Comment: This question already has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: convert date timestamp to epoch unix time and figure out number of days remaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132745/python-convert-date-timestamp-to-epoch-unix-time-and-figure-out-number-of-days)

Comment: Thank you very much to your answers, however I don't know which format use to convert my string to a date with strptime. I am doing ` dt =  datetime.strptime(time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S.%f')` but it does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.7+:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2014-03-05 07:22:26.976637+00:00').timestamp()
1394004146.976637
```

---

There are two steps:

#### [Convert input rfc-3339 time string into datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

time_str = '2014-03-05 07:22:26.976637+00:00'
utc_time = datetime.strptime(time_str[:26], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
assert time_str[-6:] == '+00:00'
```

#### [Find number of the microseconds since Epoch for given datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)

def timestamp_microsecond(utc_time):
    td = utc_time - epoch
    assert td.resolution == timedelta(microseconds=1)
    return (td.days * 86400 + td.seconds) * 10**6 + td.microseconds

print(timestamp_microsecond(utc_time))
# -> 1394004146976637
```

The advantage is that you could convert this unique number back to the corresponding UTC time:

```
utc_time = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=1394004146976637)
# -> datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 5, 7, 22, 26, 976637)
```

Follow the links if you need to support arbitrary utc offsets (not just UTC time).

If you need to accept a leap second as the input time; see [Python - Datetime not accounting for leap second properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029510/4279)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to convert this date to a unique number

The standard unix thing to do would be to convert to seconds since epoch.  However, if you just want a unique number:

```
>>> time = '2014-03-05 07:22:26.976637+00:00'
>>> int(''.join(c for c in time if c.isdigit()))
201403050722269766370000L
```

If, instead of a unique number, you want a python datetime object, then use:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> dt = parser.parse(time)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 5, 7, 22, 26, 976637, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: To complete the answer, use: dt.timestamp() which returns a unix time stamp in seconds as a float.