# Parse and combine date and time (leap seconds) from strings - python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, leap-second

I parse a date (format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) from a data file which contains multiple lines of dates.

The problem is that the data contains **leap seconds** so i'm not able to use *datetime*. How can I take into account the leap seconds (0-60), so that at the end I would have the same result if I would have used *datetime.strptime* from the string with the format above (thus, date+time), please?

I have already tried with *combine* using *date* for the date and *time* for the time string. Is it the right way or are there some others?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just [use `time.strptime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029510/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime as DT
import time
from calendar import timegm

utc_time_string = '2012-06-30 23:59:60'
utc_time_tuple = time.strptime(utc_time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[:6]
utc_dt = DT.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + DT.timedelta(seconds=timegm(utc_time_tuple))
# -> datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 1, 0, 0)
```

If the input time is not in UTC then you could handle the leap second in the `time_tuple` manually e.g., the `datetime` module may raise  `ValueError` if you pass the leap second directly or it may silently truncate `60` to `59` if it encounters a leap second in indirect (internal) calls.